# slimbox wraps DOM in a var -

Tags: mootools

I have installed Slimbox which is working fine.

However the Slimbox author has wrapped all the Slimbox code and is initializing the DOM in a var, after setting some global vars.

```
var Slimbox = (function() {

// Global variables, accessible to Slimbox only
var win = window, ie6 = Browser.ie6, options, images, activeImage = -1, activeURL, prevImage, nextImage, compatibleOverlay, middle, centerWidth, centerHeight,

// Preload images
preload = {}, preloadPrev = new Image(), preloadNext = new Image(),

// DOM elements
overlay, center, image, sizer, prevLink, nextLink, bottomContainer, bottom, caption, number,

// Effects
fxOverlay, fxResize, fxImage, fxBottom;

// now initialize the DOM
window.addEvent('domready', function() {

// *************
// This is where the problem arises. 
// I call ajax actions here, and some functions which are external to 'domready' 
// *************
pageInit();
setupFormSubmit('product_bid', 'afterPlaceBid');
setupAjaxAction('delete_validate_id_link', 'afterDelete');
setupAjaxAction('move_validate_down_link', 'afterMoveValidate');
//etc...

});
// end the DOM function



function afterMoveValidate(){  
}

function afterDelete() { 
}

// all the Slimbox functions are here too... 
etc..

//end the var Slimbox
})
```

The problem is that my external functions, while still in the var, don't have global scope, yet the Slimbox functions do.

This did work without Slimbox, where I initialized the DOM and had external functions.

Can anyone help with an idea / explanation?

thanks

Comment: This looks like a variant of the module pattern in JavaScript. If you look you should find a return statement, that reviles the "public" interface. Everything else is private functions and variables. However, I'm having problem understanding your question. Can you clarify it.

Comment: Did you add functionality to slimbox?  Please bare in mind that the load order of your JavaScript is important. So if you load a modified slimbox before you load your functions that is being called in slimbox it will fail. The script actually runs when you load it, that's why we use onDomReady. Please let me now if I did not understand the question.

Comment: @Nils, thank you for your help. I did not modify Slimbox or the initialization.  I added my functions from my original app inside the Slimbox var. Perhaps it is easier to understand viewing the js code on the web page? [link](http://thecounterfeitreport.com/product_details.php?product_id=154)   ||  If I remove the DOM & my functions and put it outside the var, and call the var from the DOM, my functions work, but only a part of Slimbox works. I don't understand "reviles the public interfsace" What can explain in more detail to help?   Thanks! Craig

Answer (score 0):

What the author of slimbox has done is implemented the model pattern. If you test the code bellow you will notice that you can not access `privateVar` or `privateFunction` from the outside. However, you can access them through `publicVar` and `publicFunction.

So everything that is put in the slimbox function (or the modelPattern bellow) is not accessible from the outside, only the parts that are "exported" in object that is returned. Because only that part will be in the "slimbox" variable (or the modelPattern bellow).

```
var modelPattern = (function() {

    // Global variables, accessible to Slimbox only
    var privateVar = 'private';

    function privateFunction() {
        console.log(privateVar);
    }

    return {
        publicVar: 'public',
        publicFunction: function() {
            console.log(privateVar);
        }
    };
})();

modelPattern.publicFunction();
if (!modelPattern.privateFunction) {
    console.log("privateFunction is not defined");
}​
```

You can see the result of the code in this fiddle, just start your javascript console so you can see the output. http://jsfiddle.net/ArE2x/

Comment: my functions are, in fact, inside the "Slimbox" var. So they should be accessible. Are you suggesting I put them outside the Slimbox var, and call them from the Slimbox var? I tried a variation of this by removing the DOM from the var and then  calling the var from the DOM. -- My functions worked, but Slimbox only partially worked. I'm looking for a solution to get may functions working along with the Slimbox model.

Comment: To help you further I need to know exactly what functions that is not working, what you expect to happen and what is happening.

Comment: inside domready, I have functions that intercept and fire ajax events, update a DB, and return a jason response  eg: 
    setupAjaxAction('move_validate_down_link', '<?php echo $objLanguage->GetText('__confirm_move_down__'); ?>', 'afterMoveValidate');

structure: (the link, alert(), and "aftermovevalidate" -- the function outside domready (but still inside the Slimbox var) which consumes the Jason response and fires a page refresh.)

Comment: The event triggers, the DB is updated, but the page refresh is not firing. The function "afterMoveValidate()" which is outside the domready but in the Slimbox var,  apparently is not globally scoped?

Comment: Exacly, nothing in the slimbox "var" is visable from the public scope, except for the parts that are returned to the slimbox "var". I made a new fiddle so you can see how to revile a function to the global scope. http://jsfiddle.net/CaEaG/